# Append two sql tables and export them as Excel document php

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I have 2 tables in the database deliverydata and deliverydata1. I want to append them and export the result as a excel sheet. Here is my sql to excel export script for deliverydata table. What code should I add to append them and export the output as excel sheet. Both the tables have the same number of columns with the same name.
Here is my code :

```
<?php


include 'db.php';
$SQL = "SELECT  WayFrom,WayTo,ConsignorName,ConsigneeName,PODStatus from deliverydata";
$header = '';
$result ='';
$exportData = mysql_query ($SQL ) or die ( "Sql error : " . mysql_error( ) );

$fields = mysql_num_fields ( $exportData );

for ( $i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++ )
{
    $header .= mysql_field_name( $exportData , $i ) . "\t";
}

while( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $exportData ) )
{
$line = '';
foreach( $row as $value )
{                                            
    if ( ( !isset( $value ) ) || ( $value == "" ) )
    {
        $value = "\t";
    }
    else
    {
        $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
        $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
    }
    $line .= $value;
 }
 $result .= trim( $line ) . "\n";
 }
  $result = str_replace( "\r" , "" , $result );

if ( $result == "" )
{
  $result = "\nNo Record(s) Found!\n";                        
}

header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
print "$header\n$result";

?>
```

Comment: You can use phpexcel for this [phpexcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)

Comment: What is not working in your current code? Undesired result? Any error?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @iainn for your suggestion. It worked :)
@rafael Yes I'm using phpexcel library
@parfait the current code was working properly but I wanted to append two tables